# Lost my Windows XP after bot-repair from the boot menu

Tags: grub2

I had ubuntu 12.04 alongside windows XP and was working fine.
Then I did following,
1. Reinstall windows XP and I lost grub
2. Booted using Ubuntu live CD and installed boot-repair
3. Did boot-repair with 'recommended repair'

Now the notebook boots with grub, but windows XP option is missing.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/6649686/

thanks,
Aniket

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 0):

You installed windows XP on `/dev/sda5` which was a logical partition.Windows can't be able to boot if it was installed on a logical partition.

So try to reinstall Windows XP on a Primary partition.

Answer (score 0):

I always do the following -

1. If you installed Windows XP and lost GRUB, then get [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) and get your Ubuntu back.
2. If you installed Ubuntu and lost Windows, use [Windows XP boot-repair](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/operatingsystems/ss/instxprepair1.htm) (from its CD/DVD) to get your Windows booting.

If you do not know how to use EasyBCD, follow the steps 2 and 3 mentioned [here](https://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd/dual-boot/linux/ubuntu/) under the *Adding Ubuntu to the Windows Bootloader* heading.